# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filtered' (Odoo 14)

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I got an attributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filtered' when trying this code:

```
  tag_ids = [self.env['account.analytic.tag'].browse(tag) for tag in analytic_tag[0][2]]
   my_tag = tag_ids.filtered(lambda q: .....)
```

when printing tag_ids, I got : `tag_ids:[account.analytic.tag(2,), account.analytic.tag(1,)]`

How can I use filtered function in this case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get a list of single recordsets, instead of a multi recordset.

Just use the list comprehension another way:

```py
tags = self.env['account.analytic.tag'].browse([tag_id for tag_id in analytic_tag[0][2]])
my_tags = tags.filtered()
```